# Error when performing connection to netwitness

Tags: php

i wanted to perform a connection to the netwitness and get real time data from the particular environment using the particular php script.If I run the php script, it will get datas from the netwitness and load data into the database. However, when I run the php script, error appear which states

```
    restapi database exists
attackdata table exists

=application/json&expiry=600&query=select%20*%20where%20alert%20exists%20%26%26%
20alert%3D%27tag_cesium%27%2C%27tag_cesium_extra%27%20%26%26%20time%3d1507605013
-u{
    "flags" : 1074200577,
    "results" : {
        "id1" : 32137775498,
        "id2" : 32137775497,
        "fields" : [
        ]
    }
}
<pre>Array
(
    [flags] => 1074200577
    [results] => Array
        (
            [id1] => 32137775498
            [id2] => 32137775497
            [fields] => Array
                (
                )

        )

)
</pre>
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\wamp\www\project-data-agi
-new\connector.php on line 72

Notice: Undefined index: results in C:\wamp\www\project-data-agi-new\connector.p
hp on line 72

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\wamp\www\project-data-agi
-new\connector.php on line 72
attackview view exists
```

My code is found below..

```
    <?php
    include 'config.php';
    /*
    *   Open connection to MYSQL database
    */

        $TimeRange  = '300'; //'1800';  // 30 minutes, 
    // [Not Configurable] Please do not touch
        $DataWithinTime = ($TimeCurrent - $TimeRange); // Gets data from 30 minutes ago
        $DataWithinTimeISO = gmdate('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z', $DataWithinTime);

        $con = mysqli_connect ($dbhost, $dbusername, $dbpassword) or die ('Error connecting: ' . mysqli_error($con));

        $db_selected = mysqli_select_db($con, $dbname);

        if(!$db_selected){
            $sql = 'CREATE DATABASE '.$dbname.'';
            if (mysqli_query($con, $sql)){
                echo "Database successfully created\n";
                $db_selected = mysqli_select_db($con, $dbname);
            } else {
                echo 'Error creating database: ' . mysqli_error() . "\n";
            }
        } else {
            echo $dbname." database exists \n";
        } 

        $query = "SELECT `id` FROM " .$dbtable;
        $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

        if (empty($result)){
            echo $dbtable." table does not exist. Creating table now. \n";
            $query = mysqli_query($con, "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " .$dbtable." (`id` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, `group` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL, `type` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, `value` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL)");
        } else {
            echo $dbtable." table exists \n";
        }

        // Use prepare statement for insert query
        $st = mysqli_prepare($con, 'INSERT INTO `'.$dbtable.'` (`group`, `type`, `value`) VALUES (?,?,?)');
        // Bind the variables to insert query params
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param ($st, 'iss', $group, $type, $value);

    /*
    *   Passing Rest API Data to MYSQL
    */
        // Method 1: Demo Data (Final Presentation Purpose)
        //$filename = 'RestData.json';

        // Method 2: Data from RSA Security Analytic Concentrator / Broker
        //$filename = 'http://'.$SAUser.':'.$SAPass.'@'.$DevIP.':'.$DevPort.'/sdk?msg=query&query=where+time='.$DataWithinTime.'-u&force-content-type=application/json';
        // $filename = 'http://'.$SAUser.':'.$SAPass.'@'.$DevIP.':'.$DevPort.'/sdk?msg=query&force-content-type=application/json&expiry=600&query=select%20*%20where%20alert%20exists%20%26%26%20time='.$DataWithinTime.'-u';
        // added on 2017-04-05
//actual one
    $filename = 'http://'.$SAUser.':'.$SAPass.'@'.$DevIP.':'.$DevPort.'/sdk?msg=query&force-content-type=application/json&expiry=600&query=select%20*%20where%20alert%20exists%20%26%26%20alert%3D%27tag_cesium%27%2C%27tag_cesium_extra%27%20%26%26%20time%3d'.$DataWithinTime.'-u';
    echo $filename;
//test one
    /*
    *   Read contents of REST data from URL
    */

        $json = file_get_contents($filename);
    echo $json;
    /*
    *   Convert REST JSON data into associative array
    */

        $resultobj = json_decode ($json, true);
        echo '<pre>' . print_r($resultobj, TRUE) . '</pre>';
        if(is_array($resultobj) || is_object($resultobj)){
            foreach ($resultobj as $obj){
                // Loop through the array
                foreach ($obj['results']['fields'] as $results){
                    $group = $results['group'];
                    $type = $results['type'];
                    $value = $results['value'];
                    mysqli_stmt_execute($st);
                }
            }
        }
        else{
            print "No data has been uploaded. \n";
        } 

        $query2 = "SELECT `id` FROM " .$dbview;
        $result2 = mysqli_query($con, $query2);

        if (empty($result2)){
            echo $dbview." does not exist. Creating view now. \n";
            //$query = mysqli_query($con, "CREATE VIEW `".$dbview."` AS SELECT id, `group`, MAX(CASE WHEN (type = 'time') THEN value ELSE NULL END) AS 'time', MAX(CASE WHEN (type = 'ip.src') THEN value ELSE NULL END) AS 'ip.src', MAX(CASE WHEN (type = 'ip.dst') THEN value ELSE NULL END) AS 'ip.dst', MAX(CASE WHEN (type = 'tcp.srcport') THEN value ELSE NULL END) AS 'tcp.srcport', MAX(CASE WHEN (type = 'tcp.dstport') THEN value ELSE NULL END) AS 'tcp.dstport', MAX(CASE WHEN (type = 'streams') THEN value ELSE NULL END) AS streams, MAX(CASE WHEN (type = 'country.dst') THEN value ELSE NULL END) AS 'country.dst', MAX(CASE WHEN (type = 'city.dst') THEN value ELSE NULL END) AS 'city.dst', MAX(CASE WHEN (type = 'latdec.dst') THEN value ELSE NULL END) AS 'latdec.dst', MAX(CASE WHEN (type = 'longdec.dst') THEN value ELSE NULL END) AS 'longdec.dst', MAX(CASE WHEN (type = 'org.dst') THEN value ELSE NULL END) AS 'org.dst', MAX(CASE WHEN (type = 'domain.dst') THEN value ELSE NULL END) AS 'domain.dst', MAX(CASE WHEN (type = 'country.src') THEN value ELSE NULL END) AS 'country.src', MAX(CASE WHEN (type = 'city.src') THEN value ELSE NULL END) AS 'city.src', MAX(CASE WHEN (type = 'latdec.src') THEN value ELSE NULL END) AS 'latdec.src', MAX(CASE WHEN (type = 'longdec.src') THEN value ELSE NULL END) AS 'longdec.src',MAX(CASE WHEN (type = 'service') THEN value ELSE NULL END) AS 'service', MAX(CASE WHEN (type = 'packets') THEN value ELSE NULL END) AS 'packets', MAX(CASE WHEN (type = 'alert.id') THEN value ELSE NULL END) AS 'alert.id', MAX(CASE WHEN (type = 'tcp.flags') THEN value ELSE NULL END) AS 'tcp.flags', MAX(CASE WHEN (type = 'ip.proto') THEN value ELSE NULL END) AS 'ip.proto', MAX(CASE WHEN (type = 'alias.host') THEN value ELSE NULL END) AS 'alias.host', MAX(CASE WHEN (type = 'alias.ip') THEN value ELSE NULL END) AS 'alias.ip', MAX(CASE WHEN (type = 'udp.srcport') THEN value ELSE NULL END) AS 'udp.srcport', MAX(CASE WHEN (type = 'org.src') THEN value ELSE NULL END) AS 'org.src', MAX(CASE WHEN (type = 'domain.src') THEN value ELSE NULL END) AS 'domain.src', MAX(CASE WHEN (type = 'email.src') THEN value ELSE NULL END) AS 'email.src', MAX(CASE WHEN (type = 'ip.srcport') THEN value ELSE NULL END) AS 'ip.srcport', MAX(CASE WHEN (type = 'user.src') THEN value ELSE NULL END) AS 'user.src', MAX(CASE WHEN (type = 'ad.domain.src') THEN value ELSE NULL END) AS 'ad.domain.src',MAX(CASE WHEN (type = 'ad.username.src') THEN value ELSE NULL END) AS 'ad.username.src', MAX(CASE WHEN (type = 'ad.computer.src') THEN value ELSE NULL END) AS 'ad.computer.src', MAX(CASE WHEN (type = 'udp.dstport') THEN value ELSE NULL END) AS 'udp.dstport', MAX(CASE WHEN (type = 'email.dst') THEN value ELSE NULL END) AS 'email.dst', MAX(CASE WHEN (type = 'ip.dstport') THEN value ELSE NULL END) AS 'ip.dstport', MAX(CASE WHEN (type = 'user.dst') THEN value ELSE NULL END) AS 'user.dst', MAX(CASE WHEN (type = 'ad.domain.dst') THEN value ELSE NULL END) AS 'ad.domain.dst', MAX(CASE WHEN (type = 'ad.username.dst') THEN value ELSE NULL END) AS 'ad.username.dst', MAX(CASE WHEN (type = 'ad.computer.dst') THEN value ELSE NULL END) AS 'ad.computer.dst', MAX(CASE WHEN (type = 'attachment') THEN value ELSE NULL END) AS 'attachment', MAX(CASE WHEN (type = 'alert') THEN value ELSE NULL END) AS 'alert' FROM ".$dbtable." GROUP BY `group` ORDER BY `group`");
            $query = mysqli_query($con, "CREATE VIEW `".$dbview."` AS SELECT id, `group`, MAX(CASE WHEN (type = 'time') THEN value ELSE NULL END) AS 'time', MAX(CASE WHEN (type = 'ip.src') THEN value ELSE NULL END) AS 'ip.src', MAX(CASE WHEN (type = 'ip.dst') THEN value ELSE NULL END) AS 'ip.dst', MAX(CASE WHEN (type = 'tcp.srcport') THEN value ELSE NULL END) AS 'tcp.srcport', MAX(CASE WHEN (type = 'tcp.dstport') THEN value ELSE NULL END) AS 'tcp.dstport', MAX(CASE WHEN (type = 'streams') THEN value ELSE NULL END) AS streams, MAX(CASE WHEN (type = 'country.dst') THEN value ELSE NULL END) AS 'country.dst', MAX(CASE WHEN (type = 'city.dst') THEN value ELSE NULL END) AS 'city.dst', MAX(CASE WHEN (type = 'latdec.dst') THEN value ELSE NULL END) AS 'latdec.dst', MAX(CASE WHEN (type = 'longdec.dst') THEN value ELSE NULL END) AS 'longdec.dst', MAX(CASE WHEN (type = 'org.dst') THEN value ELSE NULL END) AS 'org.dst', MAX(CASE WHEN (type = 'domain.dst') THEN value ELSE NULL END) AS 'domain.dst', MAX(CASE WHEN (type = 'country.src') THEN value ELSE NULL END) AS 'country.src', MAX(CASE WHEN (type = 'city.src') THEN value ELSE NULL END) AS 'city.src', MAX(CASE WHEN (type = 'latdec.src') THEN value ELSE NULL END) AS 'latdec.src', MAX(CASE WHEN (type = 'longdec.src') THEN value ELSE NULL END) AS 'longdec.src',MAX(CASE WHEN (type = 'service') THEN value ELSE NULL END) AS 'service', MAX(CASE WHEN (type = 'packets') THEN value ELSE NULL END) AS 'packets', MAX(CASE WHEN (type = 'alert.id') THEN value ELSE NULL END) AS 'alert.id', MAX(CASE WHEN (type = 'tcp.flags') THEN value ELSE NULL END) AS 'tcp.flags', MAX(CASE WHEN (type = 'ip.proto') THEN value ELSE NULL END) AS 'ip.proto', MAX(CASE WHEN (type = 'alias.host') THEN value ELSE NULL END) AS 'alias.host', MAX(CASE WHEN (type = 'alias.ip') THEN value ELSE NULL END) AS 'alias.ip', MAX(CASE WHEN (type = 'udp.srcport') THEN value ELSE NULL END) AS 'udp.srcport', MAX(CASE WHEN (type = 'org.src') THEN value ELSE NULL END) AS 'org.src', MAX(CASE WHEN (type = 'domain.src') THEN value ELSE NULL END) AS 'domain.src', MAX(CASE WHEN (type = 'email.src') THEN value ELSE NULL END) AS 'email.src', MAX(CASE WHEN (type = 'ip.srcport') THEN value ELSE NULL END) AS 'ip.srcport', MAX(CASE WHEN (type = 'user.src') THEN value ELSE NULL END) AS 'user.src', MAX(CASE WHEN (type = 'ad.domain.src') THEN value ELSE NULL END) AS 'ad.domain.src',MAX(CASE WHEN (type = 'ad.username.src') THEN value ELSE NULL END) AS 'ad.username.src', MAX(CASE WHEN (type = 'ad.computer.src') THEN value ELSE NULL END) AS 'ad.computer.src', MAX(CASE WHEN (type = 'udp.dstport') THEN value ELSE NULL END) AS 'udp.dstport', MAX(CASE WHEN (type = 'email.dst') THEN value ELSE NULL END) AS 'email.dst', MAX(CASE WHEN (type = 'ip.dstport') THEN value ELSE NULL END) AS 'ip.dstport', MAX(CASE WHEN (type = 'user.dst') THEN value ELSE NULL END) AS 'user.dst', MAX(CASE WHEN (type = 'ad.domain.dst') THEN value ELSE NULL END) AS 'ad.domain.dst', MAX(CASE WHEN (type = 'ad.username.dst') THEN value ELSE NULL END) AS 'ad.username.dst', MAX(CASE WHEN (type = 'ad.computer.dst') THEN value ELSE NULL END) AS 'ad.computer.dst', MAX(CASE WHEN (type = 'attachment') THEN value ELSE NULL END) AS 'attachment',MAX(CASE WHEN (type = 'device.type') THEN value ELSE NULL END) AS 'device.type', MAX(CASE WHEN (type = 'alert') THEN value ELSE NULL END) AS 'alert' FROM ".$dbtable." GROUP BY `group` ORDER BY `group`");
        } else {
            echo $dbview." view exists \n";
        }

    /*
    *   Close connection
    */
        mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

What is the cause of the error?? How to fix the error. Please help me. thank you.

Comment: Add `var_dump($resultobj);` after `$resultobj = json_decode($json, true);` and display the result in your question, please. Also, tell exactly which line is 71, e.g. the problematic one.

Comment: line 71 is foreach ($obj['results']['fields'] as $results){

Comment: ok. Please make what I adviced. Thanks.

Comment: so i need to declare the $results variable

Comment: Sorry I was thinking in java and c# the foreach is a bit different. for PHP you are defining it correctly, Sorry!

Comment: @Barns52, it is ok you are trying to help me.

Comment: @aendeerei, i did what you adivced, the output show array(2) {
  ["flags"]=>
  int(1074200577)
  ["results"]=>
  array(3) {
    ["id1"]=>
    float(32137775396)
    ["id2"]=>
    float(32137775395)
    ["fields"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
  }
}

Comment: I need to check something. So please write `echo '<pre>' . print_r($resultobj, TRUE) . '</pre>';` instead of `var_dump($resultobj);`, reedit the question and put there the result. In a comment is not good formatted, that's why I'm asking you to edit the question.

Comment: ooops I apologized. I have updated the code and the error as you adviced.

Comment: i will be looking forward to your solutions :)

Answer (score 1):

The `$resultobj` is an associative array through which you are trying to iterate with `foreach`. All corect. Then you are further iterating through the `['results']['fields']` array of each item. But `flags` item has no `['results']['fields']` subarray:

```
Array
(
    [flags] => 1074200577
    [results] => Array
        (
            [id1] => 32137775396
            [id2] => 32137775395
            [fields] => Array
                (
                )

        )

)
```

That's why the warning.

So, just delete `foreach ($resultobj as $obj) {...}`. It should then remain:

```
$resultobj = json_decode($json, true);
if (is_array($resultobj) || is_object($resultobj)) {
    // Loop through the array
    foreach ($resultobj['results']['fields'] as $results) {
        $group = $results['group'];
        $type = $results['type'];
        $value = $results['value'];
        mysqli_stmt_execute($st);
    }
} else {
    print "No data has been uploaded. \n";
}
```

Even though `$resultobj['results']['fields']` is empty, you will not receive the warning anymore. `foreach` will just have no effect then.

Good luck!

### Edit:

If you are using `true` as argument of `json_decode`, you don't need to check if `$resultobj` is an object anymore, because `true` ensures that the result is an associative array.